# Count rows in table with specific cell content

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to count with javascript the rows with a specific cell content.
This is the HTML code for the table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="UsersDataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>H0</th>
        <th>H1</th>
        <th>H2</th>
        <th>H3</th>
        <th>H4</th>
        <th>H5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>C0</td>
        <td>C1</td>
        <td>C2</td>
        <td>C3</td>
        <td>C4</td>
        <td><center><img src=".\pictures\green.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Green" width="20" height="20"></center></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I count all cells with `'alt="Green"'`?
Until now I have this code snippet:

```
function CountRows(TableID, alt) {
    var refTab = document.getElementById(TableID)
    var counter = 0
    for ( var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++ ) {
        alert(refTab.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML);
        if (refTab.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML === alt)
        {
            counter ++
        }
    }

    return counter
}
```

Thanks for help
Patrick

Comment: Do you wish to count rows or cells? E.g. in one row can be more cells with specified attribute, or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your could check if there's any element with the passed alt using `.querySelector('[alt="'+alt+'"]')` so you code could be like :

```
if (refTab.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector('[alt="'+alt+'"]')!=null)
{
  counter++;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function CountRows(TableID, alt) {
  var refTab = document.getElementById(TableID)
  var counter = 0
  for ( var i = 0; row = refTab.rows[i]; i++ ) {
    if (refTab.rows[i].cells[5].querySelector('[alt="'+alt+'"]')!=null)
    {
      counter++;
    }
  }

  return counter;
}

alert( CountRows('UsersDataTable','Green') );
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="UsersDataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>H0</th>
      <th>H1</th>
      <th>H2</th>
      <th>H3</th>
      <th>H4</th>
      <th>H5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>C0</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td><center><img src=".\pictures\green.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Green" width="20" height="20"></center></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>C0</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td>C5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>C0</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td><center><img src=".\pictures\green.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Green" width="20" height="20"></center></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>C0</td>
      <td>C1</td>
      <td>C2</td>
      <td>C3</td>
      <td>C4</td>
      <td><center><img src=".\pictures\green.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Green" width="20" height="20"></center></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `document.querySelectorAll("#UsersDataTable [alt='Green']")` to get what you want as follows. Then get the `length` of the returned array. That's your count.

```js
var v=document.querySelectorAll("#UsersDataTable [alt='Green']");
console.log(v.length);
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="UsersDataTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>H0</th>
    <th>H1</th>
    <th>H2</th>
    <th>H3</th>
    <th>H4</th>
    <th>H5</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>C0</td>
    <td>C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td><center><img src=".\pictures\green.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="Green" width="20" height="20"></center></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for the Response. I have some Troubles to insert the varaible 'TableID' and 'alt' into the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery it can be done like this:

```
var allElementsWithAltAttribute = $("[alt=green]");
```

Or you can use document instead in pure JS:

```
var allElementsWithAltAttribute = document.querySelectorAll('[alt=green]');
```

And to get the count:

```
var count = allElementsWithAltAttribute.length;
```

Comment: The OP only wants the ones in rows, so the selector should be `'table [alt=Green]'` or similar.